# Different session value on the other page

Tags: php, session

page 1

```
$formData = array();
$formData[0] = 'insert data done';
$_SESSION['form_data'] = $formData;
header('Location: view.php');
```

Page 2

```
if (isset($_SESSION['form_data'][0])) {
echo $_SESSION['form_data'][0];
unset($_SESSION['form_data']);
}
```

In the page 1 code, i comment out the header and put a

```
var_dump($_SESSION['form_data'][0]);
```

as what i was hope

```
"string(16) "insert data done""
```

this is correct but in the page 2 I put a

`var_dump($_SESSION['form_data'][0]);`

the output was

string(1) "i"

what I did wrong. in the page 2 i just want to echo the value and unset it but i tried to use

```
var_dump($_SESSION['form_data']);
```

the output was right

maybe my unsettling method might wrong.

Comment: Great job Petah.. I tried but i got vexed :D

Comment: Please read the formatting help in the editor, you're doing way too much work to try and get your code formatted, and it's actually hard to fix because of that :)

Comment: that were something else problem thanks for every one for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `echo $_SESSION['form_data']` ? it seems that you're getting the first letter of the string.

I think that if only one pair of key => value is set on a $_SESSION variable, it automatically reduces to its value. But i can't find any reference online.

Try to use this code on page 1:

```
$formData['someKey'] = 'insert data done';
```

and this on page 2:

```
echo $_SESSION['form_data']['someKey'];
```

let's see what happens...